# reload API call at intervals based on the current path via svelte-pathfinder

Tags: setinterval, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I'm using [svelte-pathfinder](https://github.com/sveltetools/svelte-pathfinder) to observe URL parameters that are then sent to a method which runs an async API call. I'd like to be able to re-run my API call based on the current path at an interval (for example, every 50 seconds).

stores.js (note that `fetchContests` is a method that runs a `await fetch()` call to an external API based on the `pattern` and `query` values from `svelte-pathfinder`:

```js
// routing
export const resultStore = derived([pattern, query], ([$pattern, $query], set) => {
    if ($pattern('/search/') && $query.params.q) {
        new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fetchContests('title', $query.params.q, true)
                    .then(set);
                resolve()
            }, delay)
        })
    } else if ($pattern('/')) {
        new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                fetchContests('contest_ids', dashboard, true)
                    .then(set);
                resolve({name: "testing"})
            }, delay)
        })
    }
}, []);
```

Results.svelte (where I display the results of the API call):

```html
<script>
    // data
    export let promise;
    import { resultStore } from './../stores.js';

    // layout components
    import Contest from "./Contest.svelte";
</script>

{#await promise}
    <p>Loading contests</p>
{:then}
    <ul>
        {#each $resultStore as contest}
            <Contest contest="{contest}"/>
        {/each}
    </ul>
{:catch error}
    <p>Something went wrong: {error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

This works really well in a non-repetitive way:

1. On initial page load, it runs an API call based on the current path
2. Whenever the path changes (a link click or a form submission or whatever), it runs another API call with those parameters. Each call gets the appropriate data from the API.

What I haven't been able to do is add `setInterval` to this in a way that preserves the path. So if the path is `http://localhost:8080/#!/search?q=governor` and 50 seconds have elapsed, the interval would make an API call with those current parameters to retrieve updated data. If the path is `http://localhost:8080/`, or `http://localhost:8080/#!/search?q=senator` instead when the next 50 seconds have elapsed, it would do the same with those parameters.

Originally, I thought maybe I could add `setInterval` to the API call itself, which is an `async function` that runs `await fetch`. But this didn't work, it would run multiple API calls ignoring the current path and parameter settings. I thought maybe I could run it within `resultStore` instead (above), but then it only ran after 50 seconds instead of running on initial page load and then again after each 50 second interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extracting the logic that should run every time `pattern` or `query` changes and after a given interval after that, I think this might match what you want to do?

```js
let delay = 50000

// routing
export const resultStore = derived([pattern, query], ([$pattern, $query], set) => {

    fetchAndSet($pattern, $query, set)

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetchAndSet($pattern, $query, set)
    }, delay);

    //  If you return a function from the callback, it will be called when
    //  a) the callback runs again, or b) the last subscriber unsubscribes.
    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}, []);


function fetchAndSet($pattern, $query, set) {
    if ($pattern('/search/') && $query.params.q) {
        fetchContests('title', $query.params.q, true).then(set)     
    } else if ($pattern('/')) {
        fetchContests('contest_ids', dashboard, true).then(set) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be exactly what I was missing!